# Why merge produces unexpected result when the rows of the matching columns have only one unique value?

Tags: r

When I say unexpected, I mean unexpected for me. Allow me to illustrate. We have the two data.frames:

```
b1<-data.frame(a=c("a","b"),b=1:2)
b2<-data.frame(a=c("a","b"),c=1:2)
```

Merge produces the following

```
> merge(b1,b2)
  a b c
1 a 1 1
2 b 2 2
```

But when we have the data.frames

```
b1<-data.frame(a=c("a","a"),b=1:2)
b2<-data.frame(a=c("a","a"),c=1:2)
```

merge produces the

```
> merge(b1,b2)
  a b c
1 a 1 1
2 a 1 2
3 a 2 1
4 a 2 2
```

when I expect

```
  a b c
  a 1 1
  a 2 2
```

Why the two different results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. base `merge` uses `match` on columns specified (or not specified). In case 1, it found only a single match for each value of `a` so there were no duplicates. But in case 2, it found two matches:

```
> b1$a %in% b2$a 
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

for each a and therefore returned all possible matches. See `?merge` for more information. `join` in `plyr` has the option of matching only the first match.

```
> join(b1,b2, match="first")
Joining by: a
  a b c
1 a 1 1
2 a 2 1
```